# Inquiry about A Matrix Output in 21-matrix_A_B.py

Tags: quantum-chemistry, pyscf

I'm trying to use the pyscf library for some calculations, specifically the 21-matrix_A_B.py example script for obtaining the A matrix.
https://github.com/tepl/pyscf/blob/master/examples/tddft/21-matrix_A_B.py

However, the output I'm receiving seems to be in a nested format with multiple brackets, which I didn't anticipate for a standard 2-dimensional matrix.

Could you kindly provide some clarification regarding the output format of the A matrix from this specific script?
I expected a 2-dimensional matrix, but the current output is in a nested format that's causing some confusion.

Any guidance or advice on how to interpret this output correctly would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking about the result of `get_ab` or the result of `diagonalize`?

Comment: I'm asking about the result of get_ab

Answer (score 2):

From the [source code](https://github.com/tepl/pyscf/blob/master/pyscf/tdscf/uhf.py#L113) for `get_ab` (the link is specifically to the UHF implementation, but the same idea applies for RHF, UKS etc), we can see that it initially stores `A` and `B` as 4-dimension numpy arrays:

```
def get_ab(mf, mo_energy=None, mo_coeff=None, mo_occ=None):
    r'''A and B matrices for TDDFT response function.

    A[i,a,j,b] = \delta_{ab}\delta_{ij}(E_a - E_i) + (ia||bj)
    B[i,a,j,b] = (ia||jb)

    Spin symmetry is considered in the returned A, B lists.  List A has three
    items: (A_aaaa, A_aabb, A_bbbb). A_bbaa = A_aabb.transpose(2,3,0,1).
    B has three items: (B_aaaa, B_aabb, B_bbbb).
    B_bbaa = B_aabb.transpose(2,3,0,1).
    '''
```

In 21-matrix_A_B.py, it reshapes these 4 dimensional arrays in 2D arrays so that standard matrix procedures, like determining the eigenvalues, can be applied. The matrix form essentially groups the indices so that $A_{i,a,j,b}$ becomes $A_{ia,jb}$, where each row and column represents a particular occupied-virtual pair of orbitals.

This $A_{ia,jb}$ matrix is the $A$ matrix you are interested in diagonalizing to determine TDA excited states and energies. The PySCF example forms the full TD-DFT block matrix which has the form:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
A & B \\
B^* & A^* \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

TDA is an approximation of TDDFT where we neglect the off diagonal $B$ matrix terms so we only need to diagonalize $A$

Comment: In the paper (Computing molecular excited states on a D‑Wave quantum annealer), PySCF is employed to compute the TDA matrix. Then a few lowest eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a TDA matrix are computed using the Quantum Annealer Eigensolver (QAE). How can I get this specific 'A matrix' mentioned, which appears to be the singular matrix for the TDA computation?"

Comment: Please ask a new question. For quantum annealers please use the [tag:quantum-computing] tag.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. It turns out that the question seems to be more about PySCF than D-Wave's quantum annealer. Now that I have looked deeper into this question and the follow-up question, I understand both questions better. I wrote an answer [here](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/12098/5), but now I think I see why Hadeel asked the first question (that you answered). The output (provided in my answer) has four square brackets instead of just two, so maybe the output is a 4D array still. Are you sure that 21-matrix_A_B.py "reshapes these 4 dimensional arrays in 2D arrays"?

Comment: @NikeDattani in 21-matrix_A_B.py, the `get_a_b` functions returns 4 dimensional arrays, but as you show in your answer, they reshape each of them to do 2D arrays, e.g `a = a.reshape(nocc*nvir,nocc*nvir)`, prior to putting them in a block matrix to diagonalize.

Comment: @Tyberius I see. That is in a function called `diagonalize` which I removed, because the OP wants to obtain the eigenvalues using the quantum annealer rather than with PySCF. I'll add the `reshape` command to my answer.

Comment: [This edit](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/revisions/12106/3) attempts to fix the issue of having a 4D array. Perhaps you can let me know if I've done it right!